# angular.js get links from database

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm using laravel 5 for backend and angular.js for frontend. App is completely driven by ajax requests.

I'm showing some static links(which would be always on any page visible) in my view like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in links">
    {{link.name}}
</li>
```

1. What's the best way to handle this? My view doesn't contain .blade(because of angular) in name so I'm not able to load these links throw php.
2. Should I try to make some php workaround or load it in angular throw `$http`?
3. If in angular how should I get it into this config function?

   ```
   app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     var links = ??; // http doesn't want to work here
     links.map(function(item) {
       $routeProvider.when('/'+item.url, {
         ..
       });
     });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would suggest first to integrate the AngularJS to work together with blade template engine in Laravel. This can be done easy with angular service called interpolation.
   Here is how you will make it:

   ```
   <script>
   var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

   customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
       $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
       $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
   });

   customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
       this.label = "This binding is brought you by [[ ]] interpolation symbols.";
   });
   </script>

   <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
       [[demo.label]]
   </div>
   ```

Here is angularjs page explaning the [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

This way you will not have conflict between AngularJS and Blade Template Engine

2. You should load it with AngularJS
3. You should attach the result to a $scope.links in a custom AngularJS controller. Based on the code from step 1 you can inject $http into anonymous DemoController function, and after this inside controller do something like this:

   var self = this;
   $http.get('YOUR API LINK', function (data) {
       self.links = data;
   });

Comment: thanks for that integration, I will take a look at it. But if it's gonna work wouldn't be better load it throw php? There's no need to do it throw js then.

Comment: In php part you create your API, in AngularJS part you call you api to fetch the result.

Comment: yup, but I wrote that this links will be static and user will not have to wait until ajax will come links

Comment: Then you can pass the data from php to js and use it in config

Comment: Yes, I also tried your approach, but it's throwing me an error because app.config() is called sooner than the links are fetched in controller

Comment: If you want to configurate it in app.config() you will need for this to create a provider that will be injected in app.config. Only provider will be available in config phase of angular.

Comment: You can read more about Angular Providers here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers . Take a look at the bottom of the page the table that show differences between different providers. Only Provider can help with config phase. You are welcome